# C++ calling dll by clicking button in window form

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli, dllimport

I am new to C++. I have recently built a dll that contains some functions to read data from a csv file and store them in a map container. Now I want to create a user interface to allow user to specify the full path and file name of the CSV file and then click a button to run my dll functions.

It seems Windows Forms Application may be able to do this. After creating the form, I understand that I can put some codes inside the bracket of the following functions:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {}
```

It works fine if I just manipulate the form. For example, a simple random number generator:

```
int num[7] = { 0 };
seed
srand((int)time(0));

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
num[i] = (rand() % 99) + 1;

this->label1->Text = Convert::ToString(num[0]);
this->label2->Text = Convert::ToString(num[1]);
this->label3->Text = Convert::ToString(num[2]);
...
```

However, it doesn't work if I changed this to a client program to run a dll.

For example, using msdn dll example
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms235636.aspx

I put the driver program:

```
double a = 7.4;
int b = 99;

cout << "a + b = " <<
MathLibrary::Functions::Add(a, b) << endl;
cout << "a * b = " <<
MathLibrary::Functions::Multiply(a, b) << endl;
cout << "a + (a * b) = " <<
MathLibrary::Functions::AddMultiply(a, b) << endl;
```

into the bracket of button1_Click function and follow the usual steps to include additional directory. Then I encounter a problem of adding the reference. I am using visual studio 2013, so the normal steps would be **right click project name** in solution explorer, **Add New Reference**. Then the dll will come out and check the box will do. However, visual studio cannot find the dll and therefore error LNK2028 comes out if I build the project without referencing to the dll.

So I just wonder is it possible to call some functions from a dll by clicking a button in a windows form? If yes, how can I solve the reference issue mentioned above? Or am I in the wrong direction?

Many thanks.

Comment: Always quote the **exact** error message.  And read the MSDN article for LNK2028, it explicitly talks about the kind of problem you an run into in a C++/CLI program.  In general you have to tell the compiler that your .h file does not contain managed code.  Put #pragma managed(push, off) before the #include, #pragma managed(pop) after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing C++/CLI with C++. C++/CLI is a superset of C++ which allows tight interoperation between C++ and .NET.

In your first example, you are writing .NET code, but in the second you want to reference a native DLL. Visual Studio hides it because "adding a reference" is only meant for .NET assemblies (somewhat confusingly also DLL files).

You have two choices: link the import library (MathLibrary.lib) with your program and include the appropriate headers. Considering that the `MathLibrary` example uses static class member functions, you might have an easier time with this approach. To do this, build the MathLibrary example, and add the generated lib to Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies in the properties of your C++ project.

Another approach can be using [P/Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx). I would suggest this over the other option if the functions you want to call are plain functions (not class members). C++ name mangling makes this harder and more brittle. You need to find out what the exported names of the member functions are and feed those to P/Invoke. However, you will be bound to a specific compiler with this (even version).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was useful. Follow your first suggestion, I have linked the import library with my form and include the header file in the program. The build was success and run the code will produce a form as expected. However, clicking the button seems not generating anything. I was expecting a console window given my cout codes above. Any suggestion? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Ben10, I'm not really sure, but there is a chance that .NET allocates the console differently and your cout output becomes invisible. You could try Console::WriteLine. If that doesn't work, I suggest you open a separate question for this.

Comment: without considering dll. It seems even this `private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
  Console::WriteLine("Hello World");
 }` cannot bring up the console.

Comment: @Ben10, of course, you are in a windowed application! If you want a console, you either need to call AllocConsole or set the subsystem to Console Application. (Linker->System->Subsystem). But you really should open a new question for this. If the above answer solved your original question, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score -2):

Put the DLL somewhere that VS can find it.

Comment: I used the **Browse** option to find the dll. However, when I check the box, it came out an error message saying  Could not add a reference for one of the following reasons: - Targets a higher version of the .NET Framework; - Not a .NET assembly; - Not a registered ActiveX control